# Connecting to Google SMTP through a different domain

Tags: smtp, google-apps

I've a project hosted with X domain, and the MX records are pointed to Google MX.

This project will be hosted on a dedicated server in a few weeks, but for now i need to connect to google smpt from another host with a different domain. I've associated the google app with domain X.  .

I've already tested the smpt connection to Google from Y and i can send emails. My question is, should i be doing this? This is for a small newsletter module i'll have running, sending 3 emails from 8 minutes interval, maximum 400 emails per week during 3, 4 weeks.

Does this goes agains the Google policies, connect to smpt domain from a different domain? I've already asked a question on Google Apps forum but had no answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/
It says nothing regarding max emails sent
In fact, other email providers will send mail from their domain (e.g. hotmail.com) to google, visa versa.
Not only can you send 400 messages/week, it happens all the time.